# Including generated 3rd party PHP library in Magento2

Tags: magento2, module, api, soap

I am creating a module that connects to a SOAP service, I have generated classes for this service using `wsdl2phpgenerator` which uses `autoload.php`. Placing this in "lib/" with the correct class namings makes it easy to include in Magento 1.9. How do I go about including these classes in Magento2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library should be shipped as a part of your custom module. Specify path to `autoload.php` of generated library in `composer.json` of your module. Should have something like this:

```
{
    ...
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php",
            "path-to-generated-soap-client-lib-autoload.php"
        ],
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This probably works for modules installed through the marketplace but not for modules installed by extracting them manually. Better to require the autoloader from inside registration.php.

Comment: is it possible to detail the full process please?

Comment: @snez How to add that file into registration.php, Let me code for that.

Comment: Can you please advise on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310486/magento2-install-library-in-custom-module ?

Answer (score 1):

If this library use autoload.php, you should require this library via magento composer