# Use non-namespace libraries with Magento2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to use a third party library in my Magento 2 module which I include via composer:
https://packagist.org/packages/os/php-excel

This extension isn't using namespaces and it seems that it raise some autoloading conflicts with Magento 2 when I try to use it in my own module.

What I tried first:

1. composer require os/php-excel
2. tried to use a static method from this library in one of my models:
   `\PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);`

Receiving the error:

```
Source class  "\PHPExcel_IO" for "PHPExcel_IOFactory" generation does not exist.
```

What I tried #2:

I have added the `\PHPExcel` object (which it seems that's the API object which allows you to use the features from this library ) as a parameter in my __construct():

```
namespace Fsu\Import\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\ReadFactory as DirReadFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\File\ReadFactory as FileReadFactory;

class Importer {

    /** @var  bool */
    protected $_dryRun;

    /** @var  string */
    protected $_path;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\ReadFactory */
    protected $_directoryReader;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\File\ReadFactory */
    protected $_fileReader;


    public function __construct(
        DirReadFactory $directoryReader, 
        FileReadFactory $fileReader, 
        \PHPExcel $excel //this is the object I am trying to use with DI
    )
    {
        $this->_directoryReader = $directoryReader;
        $this->_fileReader      = $fileReader;
        $this->_excelParser     = $excel;
    }

    //....
}
```

But I receive this error:

```
[ReflectionException]
Class PHPExcel does not exist
```

So do you think such libraries can be used with Magento 2 ? And what is the proper way to do it ?

Context:
I am writing a new cli command which to be used to import products and the import data is stored in .xsl files.

Thank you !

Comment: Maybe that can help you: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113782/include-external-php-library-in-magento-2-module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Source class  "\PHPExcel_IO" for "PHPExcel_IOFactory" generation does not exist.

You see *this* error message because Magento assumes, all *nonexistent* classes that end with "Factory" should be automatically generated. So as you inferred correctly, it's an autoloading problem: `PHPExcel_IOFactory` cannot be autoloaded, neither can `PHPExcel`.

The PHPExcel composer.json contains autoloading information:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "PHPExcel": "PHPExcel"
    },
    "files": ["PHPExcel.php"]
}
```

With that, both variants you tried, should work: using the class directly and via dependency injection. The problem is **not** that the classes are not namespaced - autoloading vendor libraries is handled well by composer!

What you can try:

1. force the composer autoloader to be regenerated with

   ```
   composer dump-autoload
   ```
2. Make sure, vendor/os/php-excel is readable by PHP (compare owner and permissions to core files). Maybe you ran composer require as root?

Comment: Thank you for a prompt answer!

You are right, it works now. The problem was with the library version I was requested via `composer require os/php-excel`. It's an older version.

I have updated the \composer.json  to require:
`  "os/php-excel": "dev-master" ` ;

Now the autoloading is made for this library I can use the objects. 

Problem solved, thanks!

Comment: i tried to run "composer dump-autoload" but getting following message:-

Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Generating autoload files