# During setup:di:compile getting error:- Source class "\PHPExcel_IO" for "PHPExcel_IOFactory" generation does not exist

Tags: magento2.2.4, setup-di-compile, production-mode, code-generation

When i'm running "setup:di:compile" or setting mode to "production" from "default" then getting following error:-

[image]

Please help me to resolve this problem immediately.

------Update@Start----------------

```
<?php

/**    PHPExcel root directory */
if (!defined('PHPEXCEL_ROOT')) {
    /**
     * @ignore
     */
    define('PHPEXCEL_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . '/../');
    require(PHPEXCEL_ROOT . 'PHPExcel/Autoloader.php');
}

/**
 * PHPExcel_IOFactory
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2006 - 2015 PHPExcel
 *
 * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
 * version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
 *
 * @category   PHPExcel
 * @package    PHPExcel
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006 - 2015 PHPExcel (http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel)
 * @license    http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.txt    LGPL
 * @version    ##VERSION##, ##DATE##
 */
class PHPExcel_IOFactory
{
    /**
     * Search locations
     *
     * @var    array
     * @access    private
     * @static
     */
    private static $searchLocations = array(
        array( 'type' => 'IWriter', 'path' => 'PHPExcel/Writer/{0}.php', 'class' => 'PHPExcel_Writer_{0}' ),
        array( 'type' => 'IReader', 'path' => 'PHPExcel/Reader/{0}.php', 'class' => 'PHPExcel_Reader_{0}' )
    );

    /**
     * Autoresolve classes
     *
     * @var    array
     * @access    private
     * @static
     */
    private static $autoResolveClasses = array(
        'Excel2007',
        'Excel5',
        'Excel2003XML',
        'OOCalc',
        'SYLK',
        'Gnumeric',
        'HTML',
        'CSV',
    );

    /**
     *    Private constructor for PHPExcel_IOFactory
     */
    private function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Get search locations
     *
     * @static
     * @access    public
     * @return    array
     */
    public static function getSearchLocations()
    {
        return self::$searchLocations;
    }

    /**
     * Set search locations
     *
     * @static
     * @access    public
     * @param    array $value
     * @throws    PHPExcel_Reader_Exception
     */
    public static function setSearchLocations($value)
    {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            self::$searchLocations = $value;
        } else {
            throw new PHPExcel_Reader_Exception('Invalid parameter passed.');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add search location
     *
     * @static
     * @access    public
     * @param    string $type        Example: IWriter
     * @param    string $location    Example: PHPExcel/Writer/{0}.php
     * @param    string $classname     Example: PHPExcel_Writer_{0}
     */
    public static function addSearchLocation($type = '', $location = '', $classname = '')
    {
        self::$searchLocations[] = array( 'type' => $type, 'path' => $location, 'class' => $classname );
    }

    /**
     * Create PHPExcel_Writer_IWriter
     *
     * @static
     * @access    public
     * @param    PHPExcel $phpExcel
     * @param    string  $writerType    Example: Excel2007
     * @return    PHPExcel_Writer_IWriter
     * @throws    PHPExcel_Reader_Exception
     */
    public static function createWriter(PHPExcel $phpExcel, $writerType = '')
    {
        // Search type
        $searchType = 'IWriter';

        // Include class
        foreach (self::$searchLocations as $searchLocation) {
            if ($searchLocation['type'] == $searchType) {
                $className = str_replace('{0}', $writerType, $searchLocation['class']);

                $instance = new $className($phpExcel);
                if ($instance !== null) {
                    return $instance;
                }
            }
        }

        // Nothing found...
        throw new PHPExcel_Reader_Exception("No $searchType found for type $writerType");
    }

    /**
     * Create PHPExcel_Reader_IReader
     *
     * @static
     * @access    public
     * @param    string $readerType    Example: Excel2007
     * @return    PHPExcel_Reader_IReader
     * @throws    PHPExcel_Reader_Exception
     */
    public static function createReader($readerType = '')
    {
        // Search type
        $searchType = 'IReader';

        // Include class
        foreach (self::$searchLocations as $searchLocation) {
            if ($searchLocation['type'] == $searchType) {
                $className = str_replace('{0}', $readerType, $searchLocation['class']);

                $instance = new $className();
                if ($instance !== null) {
                    return $instance;
                }
            }
        }

        // Nothing found...
        throw new PHPExcel_Reader_Exception("No $searchType found for type $readerType");
    }

    /**
     * Loads PHPExcel from file using automatic PHPExcel_Reader_IReader resolution
     *
     * @static
     * @access public
     * @param     string         $pFilename        The name of the spreadsheet file
     * @return    PHPExcel
     * @throws    PHPExcel_Reader_Exception
     */
    public static function load($pFilename)
    {
        $reader = self::createReaderForFile($pFilename);
        return $reader->load($pFilename);
    }

    /**
     * Identify file type using automatic PHPExcel_Reader_IReader resolution
     *
     * @static
     * @access public
     * @param     string         $pFilename        The name of the spreadsheet file to identify
     * @return    string
     * @throws    PHPExcel_Reader_Exception
     */
    public static function identify($pFilename)
    {
        $reader = self::createReaderForFile($pFilename);
        $className = get_class($reader);
        $classType = explode('_', $className);
        unset($reader);
        return array_pop($classType);
    }

    /**
     * Create PHPExcel_Reader_IReader for file using automatic PHPExcel_Reader_IReader resolution
     *
     * @static
     * @access    public
     * @param     string         $pFilename        The name of the spreadsheet file
     * @return    PHPExcel_Reader_IReader
     * @throws    PHPExcel_Reader_Exception
     */
    public static function createReaderForFile($pFilename)
    {
        // First, lucky guess by inspecting file extension
        $pathinfo = pathinfo($pFilename);

        $extensionType = null;
        if (isset($pathinfo['extension'])) {
            switch (strtolower($pathinfo['extension'])) {
                case 'xlsx':            //    Excel (OfficeOpenXML) Spreadsheet
                case 'xlsm':            //    Excel (OfficeOpenXML) Macro Spreadsheet (macros will be discarded)
                case 'xltx':            //    Excel (OfficeOpenXML) Template
                case 'xltm':            //    Excel (OfficeOpenXML) Macro Template (macros will be discarded)
                    $extensionType = 'Excel2007';
                    break;
                case 'xls':                //    Excel (BIFF) Spreadsheet
                case 'xlt':                //    Excel (BIFF) Template
                    $extensionType = 'Excel5';
                    break;
                case 'ods':                //    Open/Libre Offic Calc
                case 'ots':                //    Open/Libre Offic Calc Template
                    $extensionType = 'OOCalc';
                    break;
                case 'slk':
                    $extensionType = 'SYLK';
                    break;
                case 'xml':                //    Excel 2003 SpreadSheetML
                    $extensionType = 'Excel2003XML';
                    break;
                case 'gnumeric':
                    $extensionType = 'Gnumeric';
                    break;
                case 'htm':
                case 'html':
                    $extensionType = 'HTML';
                    break;
                case 'csv':
                    // Do nothing
                    // We must not try to use CSV reader since it loads
                    // all files including Excel files etc.
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            if ($extensionType !== null) {
                $reader = self::createReader($extensionType);
                // Let's see if we are lucky
                if (isset($reader) && $reader->canRead($pFilename)) {
                    return $reader;
                }
            }
        }

        // If we reach here then "lucky guess" didn't give any result
        // Try walking through all the options in self::$autoResolveClasses
        foreach (self::$autoResolveClasses as $autoResolveClass) {
            //    Ignore our original guess, we know that won't work
            if ($autoResolveClass !== $extensionType) {
                $reader = self::createReader($autoResolveClass);
                if ($reader->canRead($pFilename)) {
                    return $reader;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new PHPExcel_Reader_Exception('Unable to identify a reader for this file');
    }
}
```

I already tried [solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117230/use-non-namespace-libraries-with-magento2) but getting following problem :-

[image]
------Update@End---------------

Waiting for the reply!

Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you use any import export functionality module?

Comment: thanks for the reply,yes,i've used order export for sellers@Marketplace.

Comment: Try my answer and let me know it is working or not?

Answer (score 0):

Search in your directories `PHPExcel_IOFactory` then

Replace with `\PHPExcel_IOFactory` instead of `PHPExcel_IOFactory`

Because Magento 2 is working with Namespaces, you should add backslashes in front of class names.

> Remove `var` & `generated` folder  then Run `php bin/magento s:d:c`.

If you still facing issue then [Follow this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117230/use-non-namespace-libraries-with-magento2)

I hope it helps!

Comment: yes i got "PHPExcel_IOFactory" but when i'm using  "class \PHPExcel_IOFactory" instead of "class PHPExcel_IOFactory" then getting syntax error.how can i add backslash here?

Comment: Share your code where you use this for better understand.

Comment: please check the update part.

Comment: please help me to resolve!

Comment: I can't see `namespace` in your code.  in your file `namespace` you have to use ` \PHPExcel_IOFactory`

Comment: i've disabled this module but still getting the same issue,why?

Answer (score 0):

Some unused core php "PHPExcel_IOFactory" library was used in a custom module so after deleting this library issue get resolved.