# Include Authorizenet library into Magento 2

Tags: magento2, 3rd-party-library

I have been trying for a long time on how to include this library into my custom module. I have tried [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113782/include-external-php-library-in-magento-2-module) but no use. May be I have put it wrong.

```
{
  "name": "Vendor/module-name",
  "description": "N/A",
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "authorizenet/authorizenet": "1.8.9",
    "jms/serializer": "serializer-master-dev as 1.0"
  },
  "repositories": [{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/goetas/serializer.git"
  }],
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "100.0.1",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "proprietary"
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Vendor\\Name\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

in registration.php I added these code at the end of file

```
$vendorDir = require BP . '/app/etc/vendor_path.php';
$vendorAutoload = BP . "/{$vendorDir}/autoload.php";
/** @var \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $composerAutoloader */
$composerAutoloader = include $vendorAutoload;
$composerAutoloader->addPsr4('authorizenet\\', array(__DIR__ . '/authorizenet/authorizenet'));
```

Please help me fix this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the [Sample Code](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-php) running.  I used [Integrator Install](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html) for Magento2 and added Authorize.net require the project composer.json.

```
"require": {
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.5",
    "authorizenet/authorizenet": "^1.9"
},
```

After running 'composer update' I was able to add [createSubscription](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-php/blob/master/RecurringBilling/create-subscription.php) to a custom module model, call via a Magento CLI command, and return SUCCESS: Subscription ID.  Next moving the sample code to DI but think I've clear this question's hurdle.