# Magento 2: How To Include 3rd Party Library in Custom Module

Tags: magento2, php, api, magento2.2, composer

As an example, I'm looking to use Zendesk's API to create tickets and other things within my custom modules. They have a Packagist that can be installed via composer:

`composer require zendesk/zendesk_api_client_php`

Now I'm a bit confused on how to actually call or load this API in my custom module(s).

For example, how would you call the Zendesk API library in a custom observer module:

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalesOrderShipmentSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
         // Do something here using Zendesk API
    }
}
```

Is it declared in `MyCompany/MyModule` composer.json file?

Comment: Just call library funciton by `$value = \Zendesk\Myfile::functionName()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your modules `composer.json` should read the json file and be added to it's autoloader.

> This library should be shipped as a part of your custom module.
>   Specify path to autoload.php of generated library in composer.json of
>   your module. Should have something like this:
>
> {
>       ...
>       "autoload": {
>           "files": [
>               "registration.php",
>               "path-to-generated-soap-client-lib-autoload.php"
>           ],
>           ...
>       } }

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/96729/69

Answer (score 1):

you can include third party class file to top of `registration.php` file like this

```
require_once(BP . "/magmi/inc/magmi_defs.php"); 
require_once(BP . "/magmi/integration/inc/magmi_datapump.php");
```

and then you can direct access function like

`$dp = \Magmi_DataPumpFactory::getDataPumpInstance("productimport");`

in controller or model